# PHP form validation (sort of like captcha)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, validation

I have tried this in every way i can think of, there's a multidimensional array with 3 sets of data, each set has both a question and the corresponding awswer, i want to validate the user's answer to each question.

The problem is, when i press the submit button, the user is actually submiting the answer to the next question, which cannot be shown until the submit is pressed! This can be verified by entering an expected value like "2" and wait for the next question to be 1+1=

```
<?php
$question = array(
    0 => array(
        'question' => "1+1=",
        'answer' => 2
        ),
    1 => array(
        'question' => "2+1=",
        'answer' => 3
        ),
    2 => array(
        'question' => "4+1=",
        'answer' => 5
        )
);

$arrayIndex = array_rand($question);
$q = $question[$arrayIndex]['question'];
$a = $question[$arrayIndex]['answer'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($_POST['answer'] == $a) {
        echo "correct";
    } else {
        echo "incorrect";
    }
} else {
    echo "Answer this:";
}

print $a;
print ("
<form method='post'><br/>
<input type='text name='". $a ."' value='". $q ."'>
<input type='text' name='answer'><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit'><br/>
</form>
");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your conditional check is not valid. The `$a` in the condition is getting set to a new value, and therefore contains the new answer and not the answer to the question that the user submitted.

I have explicitly added a hidden attribute to capture the index of the question and then, check the answer accordingly.

The code can o'course be optimized and cleaned up, but here is a simple modification of your code to get the thing done.

```
<?php
$question = array(
    0 => array(
        'question' => "1+1=",
        'answer' => 2
        ),
    1 => array(
        'question' => "2+1=",
        'answer' => 3
        ),
    2 => array(
        'question' => "4+1=",
        'answer' => 5
        )
);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($_POST['answer'] == $question[$_POST['index']]['answer']) {
        echo "correct";
    } else {
        echo "incorrect";
    }
} else {
    echo "Answer this:";
}

$arrayIndex = array_rand($question);
$q = $question[$arrayIndex]['question'];
$a = $question[$arrayIndex]['answer'];


print $a;
print ("
<form method='post'><br/>
<input type='text name='". $a ."' value='". $q ."'>
<input type='hidden' name='index' value='".$arrayIndex."'>
<input type='text' name='answer'><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit'><br/>
</form>
");

?>
```